create user with ACCEPT statement in UPPERCASE (Oracle)
For Oracle i have made a script to create a user after the input of a name
var muser VARCHAR2(10)

ACCEPT muser CHAR PROMPT 'Give username :'

CREATE USER "&&muser" PROFILE "WORK" IDENTIFIED BY "Test123" PASSWORD EXPIRE DEFAULT TABLESPACE "USERS" TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP" ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
GRANT "CONNECT" TO "&&muser";
GRANT "WORK_READ" TO "&&muser";
GRANT "CLUSTER_MUTATE" TO "&&muser";

This script is working fine but the user is made in lowercase and i want it to be in uppercase i tried a lot but i can't get it done. It would be ok if it will be converted to another variable before the create and grant commands.  
`Any ideas of maby another script that wil do the trick?
I tried below commands and lots of more `
SET @muser2 = UPPER('&muser');
SELECT @muser2 := SELECT UPPER('&muser') from dual;
CREATE USER UPPER(&my_user');

